# Rtk query invalidate tags not invalidating data

Tags: reactjs, firebase, rtk-query

So i have this twitter clone where when i follow a user the posts displayed on the index page should refresh and then show the posts from the user i followed and the follow people list should also refresh removing that user. So i have added invalidate tag for the followUser function invalidating both the posts and users data but it is not working. Only when i refresh do i get the updated data. How do i get it so that without refreshing my posts list and user list are refetched and displays new data.

apiSlice
followUser

```
 followUser:builder.mutation({
    async queryFn({id,currUserId}):Promise<any>{
      try{
        let currUserDocRef = doc(db,`users/${currUserId}`);
        updateDataFirebase(currUserDocRef,'following',id)

        return {data:'ok'} 
      }

      catch(err){
        return {error:err}
      }

    },invalidatesTags:['Posts','Users']
  })
```

getPosts

```
getPosts: builder.query<Posts[],void>({
      async queryFn(currUserId):Promise<any>{
        try{
          let followingsArr=await getFollowingArrFirebase(currUserId);
         //console.log(followingsArr)
          let tweetsArr: { }[]=[];
          const q=query(collection(db,'tweets'), where("creatorId", "in" , followingsArr))   
          tweetsArr=await getDataFirebase(q)
          return { data:tweetsArr }
        }

        catch(err:any){
          return{error:err} 
        }

    },providesTags: ['Posts']}),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved it. i was not using await before a function call which returned a promise

Comment: need to thank myself for leaving this comment. needed it again today.

Comment: Hey @H.b, mind explaining this further? I am stuck with the same issue, and I believe I could be suffering from the same problem. Where do you add the await? I mean which function call?

Comment: @japheth sorry for late reply. Added await before updateDataFirebase(currUserDocRef,'following',id) in followUser

Answer (score 0):

Usually this happens when people forget to set up the middleware.
Can you please check your store setup and validate that you added your apis middleware? If you are using the development build, you should also get warnings on the console about that.

Comment: I have set up the middleware. Actually the invalidating tags is working for some queries and not for others.

Comment: solved it. i was not using await before a function call which returned a promise